# Delete an item in a list in SQLite

Tags: android

I am new to Android. Can you help me find how to delete an item for a list of data in SQLite? I have this code in `onListItemClick` in the `setPositiveButton`. What's the code to put to delete this item please? I have:

```
package tab.example.menutab;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListedesClient extends ListActivity  {
    TextView selectionc;
    public int idToModify; 
    ClientDataAdapter dm;

    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    List<String[]> names2 =null ;
    String[] stg1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listeclients);
          dm = new ClientDataAdapter(this);
          names2 = dm.selectAll();

        stg1=new String[names2.size()]; 

        int x=0;
        String stg;

        for (String[] name : names2) {
            stg = name[1]+" - "+name[2]+ " - "+name[3];

            stg1[x]=stg;
            x++;
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(   
                this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,   
                stg1);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        selectionc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selectionc);

    }      

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, final int position, long id) {

        selectionc.setText("Vous êtes sur : " + stg1[position]);
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
         .setTitle("Delete Item")
         .setMessage("are you sure to delete?")
         .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                     @Override
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     ClientDataAdapter nota = ( ClientDataAdapter) adapterView
                                 .getItemAtPosition(position);
                         ClientDataAdapter.delete(stg1[position]);

                         // Refrescamos la lista  refrech i gess but havent the methode 
                         refrescarLista(); 


                     }
             })

         .setNegativeButton("No",
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                     @Override
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                             int which) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         return;
                     }
             });
     builder.show();
    }

}
```

And for the database I have:

```
package tab.example.menutab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ClientDataAdapter {
    private static final  String DATABASE_NAME = "clientbase.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    static final String TABLE_CLIENT = "clienttable";
    private static Context context;
    static SQLiteDatabase dc;
private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;

    private static final String INSERT = "insert into "
        + TABLE_CLIENT + " (nom_complet,adresse_client,numero_telephone) values (?,?,?)";

    public ClientDataAdapter(Context context) {
        ClientDataAdapter.context = context;
        OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(ClientDataAdapter.context);
        ClientDataAdapter.dc = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        this.insertStmt = ClientDataAdapter.dc.compileStatement(INSERT);
       }

    public long insert(String nom_complet,String adresse_client,String numero_telephone) {
        this.insertStmt.bindString(1, nom_complet);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(2, adresse_client);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(3, numero_telephone);
        return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        dc.delete(TABLE_CLIENT, null, null);
    }

    public List<String[]> selectAll()
    {

        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        Cursor cursor = dc.query(TABLE_CLIENT, new String[] { "id","nom_complet","adresse_client","numero_telephone"},
                null, null, null, null, "nom_complet asc"); 

        int x=0;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String[] b1=new String[]{cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3)};

                list.add(b1);

                x=x+1;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        } 
        cursor.close();

        return list;
    }


    public void delete(int rowId) {
        dc.delete(TABLE_CLIENT, null, null); 
    }

    private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        OpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase dc) {
            dc.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CLIENT + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nom_complet TEXT NOT NULL, adresse_client TEXT NOT NULL, numero_telephone TEXT NOT NULL)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase dc, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            dc.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CLIENT);
            onCreate(dc);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This website should help you out with most problems in android database handling. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

If i understand correctly;

```
public void delete(int rowId) {
    dc.delete(TABLE_CLIENT, id + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(cursor.getString(0)) });
}
```

im not sure why the rowId is needed.

Comment: the form of the list and the methodes uses are note the same for me the database to how to do in my case it's a cople of line to insert i dont know how i m new in android